# redirect to domain without www [SSL]

Tags: .htaccess

I want redirect to domain without www ,
I tried this codes at `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and also

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

when I type www.mysite.com its work but when I type https:www.mysite.com I got this error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com. 
Peer reports it experienced an internal error. (Error code: 
ssl_error_internal_error_alert)
```

what is my mistake?

Update: I already have a valid SSL certificate.
And I use this code for redirect to HTTPS :

At top of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you have ssl certificates ?

Comment: yes and 100% sure its valid

Comment: you should check error.log and access.log for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect :

- http://www.example.com

or

- https://www.example.com

to

- http://example.com

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: thank you. But i want redirect to **https** and I have this code for SSL `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`

Comment: @Anoano my code redirects from non-ssl to ssl. Did you try this?